# performance advice regarding multiple facebook Json requests

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a facebook app which searches for facebook events near your position.The only way to do so is to search for all the places id's in your zone and then for each of those check if there is an event today.The problem I have is that the computation takes like 1-1:30 min which is kinda long. This is the code I use(might not be the best, I know):

```
foreach (var item in allPlacesIds) 
{
    RunOnUiThread (() =>loading.Text = string.Format ("Loading {0} possible events out of {1}",count,allPlacesIds.Count));
    string query = string.Format ("{0}?&fields=id,name,events.fields(id,name,description,start_time,attending_count,declined_count,maybe_count,noreply_count).since({1}).until({2})", item,dateNow,dateTomorrow);
    JsonObject result=(JsonObject)fb.Get (query, null);
    try
    {
        JsonArray allEvents= (JsonArray)((JsonObject) result ["events"])["data"];

        foreach (var events in allEvents)
        {
            Events theEvent= new Events(((JsonObject)events) ["id"].ToString(),
                                       ((JsonObject)events) ["name"].ToString(),
                                       ((JsonObject)events) ["description"].ToString(),
                                       ((JsonObject)events) ["start_time"].ToString(),
                                       int.Parse(((JsonObject)events) ["attending_count"].ToString()),
                                       int.Parse(((JsonObject)events) ["declined_count"].ToString()),
                                       int.Parse(((JsonObject)events) ["maybe_count"].ToString()),
                                       int.Parse(((JsonObject)events) ["noreply_count"].ToString()));

            todaysEvents.Add(theEvent);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
    }
    count++;
}
```

Where the try starts I used to have an if but that made it take even longer so I replaced it with a try block, as the result comes as null.

I know this isn't exactly a technical issue but I felt maybe you guys know a faster and better implementation of this, my only other option is to create and host a web service and use that just to interrogate data. the problem with that is that I need to invest a lot of money into a server/real ip/ and then I need to create a scheduled job to update the data daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each API call takes some time, the only way to make it faster is to use **Batch Requests**. Here´s the documentation about those: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Keep in mind that this will not count as one API call, it´s still the same amount, so be careful with API limits.

Comment: thank you very much for the advice, ill check it out:)